# C# Changing a part of a line of code to a variable

Tags: c#

I am using Unity3D.

I have a script to sort a list based on a certain value of a creature.

For example, the creatures have a variable saying how much food they've eaten, how many calories they currently have, and how large they are.

I want the user to be able to change the way the values are sorted by clicking a button. I don't want to pile if statements though, such as

```
if(sortType == "calories") {
    entrySortedText.text = creatureData.calories.ToString();
} else if(sortType == "food eaten") {
    entrySortedText.text = creatureData.foodEaten.ToString();
}
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
entrySortedText.text = creatureData.sortType.ToString();
```

to automatically find the variable with the name of what the sort type is in creatureData. But obviously this doesn't work, as there is no variable "sortType" in creature data, but I want it to replace what the sortType is automatically with the variable name, such as "calories" or "food eaten".

Does anyone know a way to change a part of a line of code to the value of a variable? Or do I have to just use a bunch of if statements?

Thanks. Your response is greatly valued.

P.S.

Here is the current sorting code:

```
public void LoadList() {
    foreach(Transform child in transform) {
        GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }

    List<GameObject> creatures = new List<GameObject>(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Creature").ToList());

    // Sort list based on calories
    creatures.Sort(
        delegate(GameObject i1, GameObject i2) {
            return i2.GetComponent<CreatureData>().calories.CompareTo(i1.GetComponent<CreatureData>().calories);
        }
    );

    foreach(GameObject creature in creatures) {
        GameObject entry = Instantiate(entryPrefab);
        entry.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
        entry.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = creature.GetComponent<CreatureData>().creatureName;
        entry.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = creature.GetComponent<CreatureData>().calories.ToString();
        entry.GetComponent<CreatureListEntryButton>().targetCreature = creature;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for a dictionary.

Comment: But I do not see any sorting code in the code you have posted. This is not sorting: `creatureData.calories.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sort on a property but that property will be decided at runtime. 
Let's say you have a collection named `items` and the items have a property named `Calories`. Then you can do this:

```
var sortBy = "Calories"; 
var propertyInfo = typeof(YourObject).GetProperty(sortBy);
```

Then you can sort on that:

```
var orderByCalories = items.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null));
```

Comment: What if I don't want to set it at runtime?

Comment: @rugbugreddern Ok, strange. Then when do you want to set it? At some point you have to make the decision. Compile or runtime. What other option is there?

Comment: @rugbugredfern please see above comment. Sorry misspelled your name.